# How to customise the reset password link

Tags: laravel

I have a small problem with the password reset link.

Once I click on it, it brings me `localhost/token/email` instead of `locahost:8000/token/email`.

How can I customize it

Comment: `token/email`? do you mean `password/email`?

Comment: I believe you can change APP_URL in env to be localhost:8000

Answer (score 4):

All routes urls follow the `config('app.url')` which is defined in your `.env` as `APP_URL`, set it there properly

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```